Parsing concatenated DateTime values
So I have these 2 values coming in to my program:
EDate = "20240328";
ETime = "145222"

These are essentially a timestamp of a transaction, I need to convert this to this format:
2024-03-28T19:52:22.000Z

I've tried a number of things and this is the only way I have found to get it right.
CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
DateTime dateValue;
String format = "yyyy-MM-dd\\THH:mm:ss:fff\\Z";
string EDate  = "20240328";
string ETime  = "145222";

string dtString = String.Concat(EDate, ETime);
int y = Convert.ToInt32(dtString.Substring(0,4));
int mm = Convert.ToInt32(dtString.Substring(4,2));
int dd = Convert.ToInt32(dtString.Substring(6,2));
int hh = Convert.ToInt32(dtString.Substring(8,2)) + 5; // Our servers are on Central time
int m = Convert.ToInt32(dtString.Substring(10,2));
int ss = Convert.ToInt32(dtString.Substring(12,2));

dateValue = new DateTime(y, mm, dd, hh, m, ss);
// Result: 2024-03-28T19:52:22.000Z
Console.WriteLine(dateValue.ToString(format));  

Is there an easier way?

try DateTime.TryParseExact

Already tried, couldn't get it right

The dateValue always came out as  01/01/0001 00:00:00

This will mostly get you there:
// dateValue should be yyyyMMdd. timeValue should be HHmmss. No spaces or separators.
// Will throw a FormatException if values are formatted differently.
string FormatTimestamp(string dateValue, string timeValue)
{
    string inputFormat = "yyyyMMddHHmmss";
    string outputFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd\\THH:mm:ss:fff\\Z";
    return DateTime.ParseExact(dateValue + timeValue, inputFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString(outputFormat);
}

With the caveat the input hours don't (yet!) match the desired output. And while we could .AddHours(5) easily enough, this would fail every time daylight savings changes.
So let's make some changes to account for this:
// dateValue should be yyyyMMdd. timeValue should be HHmmss
// Will throw a FormatException if values are formatted differently.
string FormatTimestamp(string dateValue, string timeValue)
{
    string inputFormat = "yyyyMMddHHmmss";
    string outputFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd\\THH:mm:ss:fff\\Z";

    var parsedDate = DateTime.ParseExact(dateValue + timeValue, inputFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    return parsedDate.ToUniversalTime().ToString(outputFormat);
}

Now we should get the correct answer no matter what time of year this runs and no matter what time of year the input date describes, as long as the system running this continues to use the correct time zone information with that process.
Note this could be a one-liner if we really wanted:
// dateValue should be yyyyMMdd. timeValue should be HHmmss
// Will throw a FormatException if values are formatted differently.
string FormatTimestamp(string dateValue, string timeValue)
{
    return DateTime.ParseExact(dateValue + timeValue, "yyyyMMddHHmmss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToUniversalTime().ToString();
}


Finally, I suspect the existing original code already gets this wrong when it happens to parse dates out of season for daylight savings, when the offset should be -6 instead of -5. It's also possible there are work-arounds for this flaw elsewhere in the larger system, such that the correct thing to do here, at least for the moment, is actually create the flawed result for those values... to preserve the existing incorrect behavior rather than introduce a breaking change into the larger system.
In that situation, the .AddHours(5) solution (with appropriate comments) will be correct:
// dateValue should be yyyyMMdd. timeValue should be HHmmss. No spaces or separators.
// Will throw a FormatException if values are formatted differently.
string FormatTimestamp(string dateValue, string timeValue)
{
    string inputFormat = "yyyyMMddHHmmss";
    string outputFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd\\THH:mm:ss:fff\\Z";
    // This is wrong for daylight savings inputs where the offset should be -6 (should use ToUniversalTime() instead of AddHours() )
    // But the wrong value is expected by system XYZ and an adjustment is made there
    return DateTime.ParseExact(dateValue + timeValue, inputFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).
               AddHours(5).ToString(outputFormat);
}

There is a similar issue with the original code for times after 7:00 PM, within 5 hours of the end of the day. The original code would have created invalid values or failed completely... but it's possible that was expected and corrected by a downstream process.
